# Do kotlin DTOs have to be Data classes?

Tags: spring, kotlin

This doesn't work for me. Seems quite simple. Any ideas what maybe wrong? I don't really want to use a Data class, as I want to subclass the base DTO to create several subclass DTOs (and in Kotlin, you cannot subclass a superclass that is a data class - it needs to be sealed, abstract, and open in some way).

***DTO***

```
    internal sealed class ProjectDTO (
    open var _id: ObjectId?,
    open var name: String,
    open var country: String,
    open var sicCode: String,
    open var sicDescription: String,
    open var screenType: String?,
){
    // Add validations in an init block
}
```

***Controller***

```
@PostMapping
suspend fun createProject(@RequestBody request: ProjectDTO): ResponseEntity<ProjectDTO> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ResponseEntity(projectService.createProject(request), HttpStatus.CREATED)
    }
}
```

***JSON API REQUEST***

```
{
    "name": "testDTO",
    "country": "testDTO",
    "sicCode": "testDTO",
    "sicDescription": "testDTO",
    "screenType": "testDTO"
}
```

***Error***

```
{
    "status": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "code": 400,
    "timestamp": "2023-11-03T22:53:11.030998",
    "message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class com.example.timesheetapi.dtos.ProjectDTO]"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn’t have to be a `data` class, but it cannot be a `sealed` class because sealed classes are abstract.

Comment: Changing sealed to open got rid of the error. But why are sealed and abstract classes not allowed?

Comment: I now get a new error though, "lateinit property projectRepo has not been initialized"

Comment: I assume because it has to instantiate it to use it. The other issue, we’d have to see the associated code to help with that.

Comment: Thanks! Link to other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77421229/repo-not-being-recognised-in-spring-kotlin-late-initialisation-does-not-work